# Any idea why JFrame is having this glitch?

Tags: java, swing, input, jframe, box

My JFrame is having a glitch. When I run my code, the code first takes 8 values and is supposed to draw them onto the jframe window, and it does but the window seems to capture whatever's behind the frame on my windows desktop. So, you can see in the image it captures my Jintelligence box, and in the other it captures my wallpaper and that's the background. I just want a plain normal background. Not sure why this is happening. Any ideas?

```
> import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.*;


public class Distance extends JFrame {
    String longer;
    String input;
    int line1_x1, line1_y1, line1_x2, line1_y2;
    int line2_x1, line2_y1, line2_x2, line2_y2;
    double l1distance;
    double l2distance;
    double distl1;
    double distl2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Distance frame = new Distance();
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setTitle("LINE DRAWER");
        frame.getvalues();
        frame.getdistance();
        frame.getlongest();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void getvalues () {
        //Line 1

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the X1 coordinate for Line 1 here:");
        line1_x1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("And the Y1 coordinate for Line 1:");
        line1_y1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the X2 coordinate for Line 1 here:");
        line1_x2 = Integer.parseInt(input);
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Plus the Y2 coordinate for Line 1:");
        line1_y2 = Integer.parseInt(input);
        //Line 2
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Now, enter the X1 coordinate the 2nd line:");
        line2_x1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("And the Y1 coordinate for the 2nd line:");
        line2_y1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Then the X2 coordinate here:");
        line2_x2 = Integer.parseInt(input);
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("And lastly, the Y2 coordinate:");
        line2_x2 = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }
    public void getdistance() {
        distl1 = Math.pow((line1_y2 - line1_y1),2) + Math.pow((line1_x2 - line1_x1),2);
        distl2 = Math.pow((line2_y2 - line2_y1),2) + Math.pow((line2_x2 - line2_x1),2);
        //Math.sqrt((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1) + (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1));\
         l1distance = Math.abs(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(distl1)));
         l2distance = Math.abs(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(distl2)));
    }
    public void getlongest(){
        if(l1distance > l2distance){
        longer = "Line One";
        }
        else if(l1distance == l2distance){
            longer = "The Lines are Equal";
        }
        else if(l2distance > l1distance){
            longer = "Line Two";
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.drawLine(line1_x1, line1_y1, line1_x2, line1_y2);
        g2d.drawString("Line 1 Origin: (" + line1_x1 + "," + line1_y1 +")", line1_x1-15, line1_y1-15);
        g2d.drawString("Line 1 End: (" + line1_x2 + "," + line1_y2 +")", line1_x2+15, line1_y2+ 15);
        g2d.drawLine(line2_x1, line2_y1, line2_x2, line2_y2);
        g2d.drawString("Line 2 Origin: (" + line2_x1 + "," + line2_y1 +")", line2_x1-15, line2_y1-15);
        g2d.drawString("Line 2 End: (" + line2_x2 + "," + line2_y2 +")", line2_x2+15, line2_y2+ 15);
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Batang", Font.BOLD, 10));
        g2d.drawString("Line 1's Distance is: " + l1distance + ".", 50,400);
        g2d.drawString("Line 2's Distance is: " + l2distance + "." ,50,430);
        g2d.drawString("The longer line is: " + longer + "." ,50,450);

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I'm new to JFrame so this might not be useful, but have you tried `frame. setBackground(Color.WHITE)`?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Swing application that has a drawing area, you create a drawing `JPanel` for the `JFrame`.  You do not draw directly on the `JFrame`.

Oracle has a really nice [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  There's a section on [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) that shows you step-by-step how to create a drawing `JPanel`.

Using the OP's code as a starting point, here's the GUI I came up with.  I made the `JOptionPane` code a control `JPanel` for a better user experience.

[image: Draw Lines GUI]

The first thing I did was to create a `Line` class.  The `Line` class holds an origin `java.awt.Point` and a destination `java.awt.Point`.  This way, I could define two `Line` instances.

Next, I created a `JFrame` and a drawing `JPanel`.  The code to create the `JFrame` is in the `run` method of the main class.  The code to create a drawing `JPanel` is in the `DrawingPanel` class.

The `DrawingPanel` class draws two lines, annotates their endpoints, and displays summary information at the bottom of the drawing.  All the `paintComponent` method does is paint.  The calculations done in this method are minimal and could be done in the `Line` class.

The `SubmitListener` class processes the line coordinates and creates two lines to be drawn. The bounds of the lines are somewhat inside of the drawing `JPanel` bounds so that the annotations can be seen.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawLinesGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DrawLinesGUI());
    }
    
    private int drawingPanelWidth;
    private int drawingPanelHeight;
    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    private JLabel messageLabel;
    
    private JTextField line1X1Field;
    private JTextField line1Y1Field;
    private JTextField line1X2Field;
    private JTextField line1Y2Field;
    private JTextField line2X1Field;
    private JTextField line2Y1Field;
    private JTextField line2X2Field;
    private JTextField line2Y2Field;
    
    private Line[] lines;
    
    public DrawLinesGUI() {
        this.drawingPanelWidth = 600;
        this.drawingPanelHeight = 600;
        this.lines = new Line[2];
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Lines");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(drawingPanelWidth, 
                drawingPanelHeight);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createControlPanel(), BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        int fieldWidth = 6;
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 15, 5);
        gbc.gridwidth = 5;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        
        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Type the coordinates for two lines");
        panel.add(titleLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel line1Label = new JLabel("Line 1");
        panel.add(line1Label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel origin1Label = new JLabel("Origin");
        panel.add(origin1Label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        JLabel xLabel = new JLabel("X:");
        panel.add(xLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        line1X1Field = new JTextField(fieldWidth);
        panel.add(line1X1Field, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        JLabel yLabel = new JLabel("Y:");
        panel.add(yLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        line1Y1Field = new JTextField(fieldWidth);
        panel.add(line1Y1Field, gbc);
        
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 15, 5);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel destination1Label = new JLabel("Destination");
        panel.add(destination1Label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        xLabel = new JLabel("X:");
        panel.add(xLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        line1X2Field = new JTextField(fieldWidth);
        panel.add(line1X2Field, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        yLabel = new JLabel("Y:");
        panel.add(yLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        line1Y2Field = new JTextField(fieldWidth);
        panel.add(line1Y2Field, gbc);
        
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridwidth = 5;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel line2Label = new JLabel("Line 2");
        panel.add(line2Label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel origin2Label = new JLabel("Origin");
        panel.add(origin2Label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        xLabel = new JLabel("X:");
        panel.add(xLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        line2X1Field = new JTextField(fieldWidth);
        panel.add(line2X1Field, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        yLabel = new JLabel("Y:");
        panel.add(yLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        line2Y1Field = new JTextField(fieldWidth);
        panel.add(line2Y1Field, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel destination2Label = new JLabel("Destination");
        panel.add(destination2Label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        xLabel = new JLabel("X:");
        panel.add(xLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        line2X2Field = new JTextField(fieldWidth);
        panel.add(line2X2Field, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        yLabel = new JLabel("Y:");
        panel.add(yLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        line2Y2Field = new JTextField(fieldWidth);
        panel.add(line2Y2Field, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 5;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        messageLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        messageLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        panel.add(messageLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton button = new JButton("Submit Lines");
        button.addActionListener(new SubmitListener());
        panel.add(button, gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        public DrawingPanel(int width, int height) {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            if (lines[0] != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                int line1_x1 = lines[0].getOrigin().x;
                int line1_y1 = lines[0].getOrigin().y;
                int line1_x2 = lines[0].getDestination().x;
                int line1_y2 = lines[0].getDestination().y;
                int line2_x1 = lines[1].getOrigin().x;
                int line2_y1 = lines[1].getOrigin().y;
                int line2_x2 = lines[1].getDestination().x;
                int line2_y2 = lines[1].getDestination().y;
                
                g2d.drawLine(line1_x1, line1_y1, line1_x2, line1_y2);
                g2d.drawString("Line 1 Origin: (" + line1_x1 + "," + line1_y1 + ")", 
                        line1_x1 - 15, line1_y1 - 15);
                g2d.drawString("Line 1 End: (" + line1_x2 + "," + line1_y2 + ")", 
                        line1_x2 + 15, line1_y2 + 15);
                g2d.drawLine(line2_x1, line2_y1, line2_x2, line2_y2);
                g2d.drawString("Line 2 Origin: (" + line2_x1 + "," + line2_y1 + ")", 
                        line2_x1 - 15, line2_y1 - 15);
                g2d.drawString("Line 2 End: (" + line2_x2 + "," + line2_y2 + ")", 
                        line2_x2 + 15, line2_y2 + 15);
                
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.setFont(new Font("Batang", Font.BOLD, 10));
                double line1Distance = distance(lines[0].getOrigin(), 
                        lines[0].getDestination());
                double line2Distance = distance(lines[1].getOrigin(), 
                        lines[1].getDestination());
                String string1 = String.format("%.1f", line1Distance);
                String string2 = String.format("%.1f", line2Distance);
                
                int y = drawingPanelHeight - 45;
                g2d.drawString("Line one's length is: " + string1 + ".", 50, y);
                g2d.drawString("Line two's length is: " + string2 + ".", 50, y + 15);
                g2d.drawString(getLongerLine(line1Distance, line2Distance) + 
                        ".", 50, y + 30);
            }
        }
        
        private double distance(Point origin, Point destination) {
            return origin.distance(new Point2D.Double(destination.x, destination.y));
        }
        
        private String getLongerLine(double l1distance, double l2distance) {
            String longer;
            
            if (l1distance > l2distance) {
                longer = "Line one is the longer line";
            } else if (l1distance < l2distance) {
                longer = "Line two is the longer line";
            } else {
                longer = "The lines are equal";
            }
            
            return longer;
        }
    }
    
    public class SubmitListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            messageLabel.setText(" ");
            lines[0] = null;
            lines[1] = null;
            
            int[] x = new int[4];
            int[] y = new int[4];
            x[0] = valueOf(line1X1Field.getText().trim(), drawingPanelWidth);
            y[0] = valueOf(line1Y1Field.getText().trim(), drawingPanelHeight);
            x[1] = valueOf(line1X2Field.getText().trim(), drawingPanelWidth);
            y[1] = valueOf(line1Y2Field.getText().trim(), drawingPanelHeight);
            x[2] = valueOf(line2X1Field.getText().trim(), drawingPanelWidth);
            y[2] = valueOf(line2Y1Field.getText().trim(), drawingPanelHeight);
            x[3] = valueOf(line2X2Field.getText().trim(), drawingPanelWidth);
            y[3] = valueOf(line2Y2Field.getText().trim(), drawingPanelHeight);
            
            int width = drawingPanelWidth - 100;
            int height = drawingPanelHeight - 100;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (x[i] < 50 || x[i] > width) {
                    messageLabel.setText("The coordinate must be "
                            + "between 50 and " + width);
                    return;
                }
                
                if (y[i] < 50 || y[i] > height) {
                    messageLabel.setText("The coordinate must be "
                            + "between 50 and " + height);
                    return;
                }
            }
            
            lines[0] = new Line(new Point(x[0], y[0]), new Point(x[1], y[1]));
            lines[1] = new Line(new Point(x[2], y[2]), new Point(x[3], y[3]));
            
            repaint();
        }
        
        private int valueOf(String text, int limit) {
            try {
                int value = Integer.valueOf(text);
                return (value >= 0 && value <= limit) ? value : -1;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Line {
        
        private final Point origin;
        private final Point destination;
        
        public Line(Point origin, Point destination) {
            this.origin = origin;
            this.destination = destination;
        }

        public Point getOrigin() {
            return origin;
        }

        public Point getDestination() {
            return destination;
        }
        
    }

}
```